# Images folder pictures in eval repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I use photos **without any folder**, `<asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("PresidentPhotoPath") %>' runat="server" />` , it works.

However, **when I use the photos under Images folder**, the pictures are not shown and I get a blank screen only. Here is the code I'm using:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1">
        <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" 
                        ImageUrl='"/Images" + <%# Eval("PresidentPhotoPath") %>' 
                        runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change asp:Image to code bellow:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" 
     ImageUrl='<%# string.Format("~/Images/{0}", Eval("PresidentPhotoPath")) %>' 
     runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a code-behind method to build the string for you, like this:

```
protected string BuildPath(string photoPath)
{
    return "Images/ + photoPath;
}
```

> Note: Consider naming this something more useful than `BuildPath` as that is fairly generic, just picked that name because nothing better came to mind immediately.

Now in your markup you can just call the method, like this:

```
ImageUrl='<%# BuildPath(Eval("PresidentPhotoPath")) %>'
```

I recommend this approach for the following reasons:

- The markup does not contain any complex logic whatsoever, just a method call with the `Eval()` value
- It is easier to debug the logic versus embedded code blocks
- You can leverage the power of Visual Studio compiler to catch syntax errors at compile-time versus run-time errors when the logic is embedded into the binding syntax of the markup